# How to apply default style to control in custom control

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a custom control which is dynamically adding a number of checkboxes. I can't figure out how to apply a default style to them from code in the custom control (from the generic.xaml file)

Comment: Are you dynamically adding them in the C# implementation of your customer control or via an ItemsControl?

Comment: I'm dynamically adding them in the C# implementation of the custom control.

Answer (score 2):

I am having a shot in the dark here, but do you have a default "theme" file that you want to apply to dynamically added UIelements in some custom UserControl?

if so,

Try something like:

```
public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Uri uri = new Uri(@"QuoteInterface;component/Theme/WhistlerBlue.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            ImplicitStyleManager.SetResourceDictionaryUri(LayoutRoot, uri);
            ImplicitStyleManager.SetApplyMode(LayoutRoot, ImplicitStylesApplyMode.Auto);
            ImplicitStyleManager.Apply(LayoutRoot);
        }
```

That seems to work for me, even when I add dynamically generated user controls

Comment: I've not had a play with the StyleManager stuff, that's in the toolkit right? I'll check it out and see if it does what I need. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is party of the Silverlight Toolkit for those interested http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203&referringTitle=Home